# Neo4j OGM Unable to process ZonedDateTime field on class my.class.Class. Check the mapping

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, zoneddatetime

I am trying to persist a @NodeEntity which has a field of type java.time.ZonedDateTime into my Neo4j database using the Bolt driver, but all I get is this warning message:

> org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : Unable to process AT on class nz.co.class.project.point.Point. Check the mapping.

I am using the following libraries:

- OpenJDK 11
- Spring Boot (2.2.0.RELEASE)
- Spring Data Neo4j (5.2.0.RELEASE)
- Neo4j (3.5.12)
- Neo4j-OGM (3.2.1)
- Neo4j-OGM-Bolt-Driver (3.2.1)
- Neo4j-OG-Bolt-Native-Types (3.2.1)

The result is the node entity being saved in the Neo4j database but without the ZonedDateTime attribute.

Am I doing something wrong? It is my understanding that OGM version 3.2.X supports all java dates in "java.time" package.

Here is a working example of the issue:

https://github.com/lcichero/neo4j-ogm-zoneddatetime.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:
The previous answer was not correct, sorry for this.
I looked again into our sources because your comment gave me some doubts.

You need to explicitly enable the type conversion (this will get covered in the docs).
For a Spring Boot application you can do this in the `application.properties` by adding

```
spring.data.neo4j.use-native-types=true
```

And you will see something like

```
Request: UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`Point`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-2, props={x=14.5, y=43.5, at=2018-06-23T00:00+12:00}}]}
```

if you set the logging for *org.neo4j.ogm* to *DEBUG*.

For Neo4j-OGM the configuration would be

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
    .uri("bolt://neo4j:password@localhost")
    .useNativeTypes()
    .build()
```

as described in the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/3.2/reference/#reference:native-property-types:optin).

Why do you have to explicitly enable this? Because we won't destroy and be able to read pre Neo4j-OGM 3.2 users' data in the database by storing the "new" native types instead of the converted values.

Old answer

> We haven't yet published the 3.2. documentation, so I link to the sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/13709b86da9d7bbd3d444e0c3eda6a771c9d48d0/neo4j-ogm-docs/src/main/asciidoc/reference/nativetypes.adoc).
>
> The supported temporal types are `Date`, `Time`, `LocalTime`, `DateTime`, `LocalDateTime` and `Duration` but as you can see not `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Oh ok, since datetimes from Neo4j were coming as ZonedDateTime I thought it was a bidirectional mapping. Thanks for the link to documentation.

Comment: Oh, your -maybe accidental- hint was perfect (also for you ;) )